# importing unstructured log file into pandas

Tags: python, pandas

can anyone here show me how to import unstructured file into pandas ?

what I mean by unstructured is:

- log file with lines having variable length like this:

```
2021-01-26T09:40:01.192Z info hostd[2101947] [Originator@6876 sub=Default opID=823a15d0] Accepted password for user root from 127.0.0.1
2021-01-26T09:40:01.192Z info hostd[2101947] [Originator@6876 sub=Vimsvc opID=823a15d0] [Auth]: User root
2021-01-26T09:40:01.193Z info hostd[2101947] [Originator@6876 sub=Vimsvc.ha-eventmgr opID=823a15d0] Event 24138 : User root@127.0.0.1 logged in as pyvmomi
2021-01-26T09:40:01.268Z info hostd[2101940] [Originator@6876 sub=Vimsvc.ha-eventmgr opID=823a15de user=root] Event 24139 : User root@127.0.0.1 logged out (login time: Tuesday, 26 January, 2021 09:40:01 AM, number of API invocations: 0, user agent: pyvmomi)
```

i tried multiple things and did some googling but every body seems to be importing nicely structured CSV files and cant find any log files imports references, (I'm not a programmer, just trying to write this small program in pandas)

*multiple things like:

```
# giving a range for column names but this is not adequate if I want to search throught the logs for errors later I'd have to use all 54 columns ?! 
 
pd.read_csv("mylog",sep='\s+',header=None,error_bad_lines=False, engine="python",quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,names=range(55))

# or putting everything into index :D 
pd.read_csv("mylog",sep='\t', lineterminator='\n', index_col=0)
*oh yeah, want to use timeframe as INDEX column* 

pd.read_csv("mylog", sep = None, iterator = True)
```

the idea is to

- have timeframe as index
- other entries in second (or second & third) column for easier string / errors searches

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to first parse the file, then edit its content, and finally create a DataFrame from it.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd


with open("mylog.txt") as f:
  content = f.read()

# data pattern
p = re.compile(r"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z) (\w+) ([\w\[\]]+) (\[[^\]]+]) (.+)")

data = [p.match(line).groups() for line in content.splitlines()]

# this is my guess, you can change the labels according to your problem
columns = ["date", "level", "node", "origin", "message"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

Which outputs:

```py
                       date  ...                                            message
0  2021-01-26T09:40:01.192Z  ...     Accepted password for user root from 127.0.0.1
1  2021-01-26T09:40:01.192Z  ...                                  [Auth]: User root
2  2021-01-26T09:40:01.193Z  ...  Event 24138 : User root@127.0.0.1 logged in as...
3  2021-01-26T09:40:01.268Z  ...  Event 24139 : User root@127.0.0.1 logged out (...
[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

Once you got the dataframe, you can do every other option, like setting the date as index.

```py
>>> df.set_index("date")
                         level  ...                                            message
date                            ...                                                   
2021-01-26T09:40:01.192Z  info  ...     Accepted password for user root from 127.0.0.1
2021-01-26T09:40:01.192Z  info  ...                                  [Auth]: User root
2021-01-26T09:40:01.193Z  info  ...  Event 24138 : User root@127.0.0.1 logged in as...
2021-01-26T09:40:01.268Z  info  ...  Event 24139 : User root@127.0.0.1 logged out (...
[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

EDIT:

To check lines that to **not** match this regex, you can do something like this.

```py
data = [(i, p.match(line)) for (i, line) in enumerate(content.splitlines())]
```

Then, once got this list of tuples in the format `(<number>, <Match_or_None>)`, you can check which lines are not identified by the regex match and update the regex/question accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your reply @crissal, this gives an error: 
```
    data = [p.match(line).groups() for line in content.splitlines()]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' 
```

Comment: This means that some lines don't match this pattern.

Comment: that was my initial problem with pandas, where pandas was expecting same number of columns but lines arew different length...good idea to start with regex tho

Comment: Read the edit. To have a more readable output, you can wrap the `p.match()` inside a `bool()` cast; this way, a correct match is mapped as `True`, and an incorrect match is mapped as `False`.